# Python spread skip cell

Tags: python, google-sheets, spread

Im writing a script which will crawl data and insert it to google sheet.

My problem: When I use update_row, i need to skip the column which there is running a google sheet function.

I try to insert "" to skip it but it'll break the function, any solution?

P/s: Sorry of my bad at English

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And also, can you provide your current script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You should provide your script (only the inserting part), how does the google sheet look like, example input and expected output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.